# Processing multi-line input - Loop vs Regex

Tags: regex, performance, perl

I am trying to look for a specific keyword in multi-line input string like this,

```
this is input line 1
this is the keyword line
this is another input line
this is the last input line
```

The multi-line input is stored in a variable called "$inputData". Now, I have 2 ways in mind to look for the word "keyword",

**Method 1:**
Using split to put the lines into an array using "\n" separator and iterate and process each line using foreach loop, like this,

```
my @opLines = split("\n", $inputData);

# process each line individually
foreach my $opLine ( @opLines )
{
    # look for presence of "keyword" in the line
    if(index($opLine, "keyword") > -1)
    {
        # further processing
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**
Using regex, as below,

```
if($inputData =~ /keyword/m)
{
    # further processing
}
```

I would like to know how these 2 methods compare with each other and What would be the better method with regards to actual code performance and execution time. Also, is there a better and more efficient way to go about this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @opLines = split("\n", $inputData);
```

Will create variable `@opLines`, allocate memory, and search `"\n"` trough whole `$inputData` and write found lines into it.

```
# process each line individually
foreach my $opLine ( @opLines )
{
```

Will process the whole bunch of code for each value in array `@opLines`

```
    # look for presence of "keyword" in the line
    if(index($opLine, "keyword") > -1)
```

Will search for the `"keyword"` in each line.

```
    {
        # further processing
    }
}
```

And comapare

```
if($inputData =~ /keyword/m)
```

Will search for the `"keyword"` and stops when find first occurrence.

```
{
    # further processing
}
```

And now guess, what will be faster and consume less memory (which affects speed as well). If you are bad in guessing use [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) module.

According [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) `m` regular expression modifier: *Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start or end of line only at the left and right ends of the string to matching them anywhere within the string.* I don't see neither `^` nor `$` in your regexp so it is useless there.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Didnt really get that last part though with the ^ and $, could you clarify? Sorry, am a bit new with regex...

Comment: You simply don't have to use the `m` modifier after your regexp unless you use `^` or `$` in your regexp. It will work same.